# While Loop in Swift Needs declaration?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a tic-tac-toe game where there are 9 buttons, and 9 image views, and each button corresponds to an image view. When the button is pressed, it changed the image view to a picture of an X or an O corresponding to which player pressed the button. Now, I have a variable set up for each of the buttons, and depending on who pressed the button, it will change the variable to 1, or 10(from 0). I need a for or while statement to continuously check to see if a win has occurred. this is the code I have for my while statement, but it will not work. Any suggestion helps!

```
var i = 0
while (i < 5)
{
//execute code here
i++
}
```

All that will display for this code is a red error showing: Expected Declaration with the emphasis on the W in while. Code them fails to build when attempted to run.

```
import UIKit




class ViewController: UIViewController {
var i = 0
while (i < 5)
{
//execute code here
i++
}




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
//end overrides




@IBOutlet var topLeft: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var topLeftB: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var topCenter: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var topCenterB: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var topRight: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var topRightB: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var middleLeft: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var middleLeftB: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var middleCenter: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var middleCenterB: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var middleRight: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var middleRightB: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var bottomLeft: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var bottomLeftB: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var bottomCenter: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var bottomCenterB: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var bottomRight: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var bottomRightB: UIButton!


@IBOutlet var resetButton: UIButton!

var playerTurn = 0
var topLeftScore = 0
var topCenterScore = 0
var topRightScore = 0
var middleLeftScore = 0
var middleCenterScore = 0
var middleRightScore = 0
var bottomLeftScore = 0
var bottomCenterScore = 0
var bottomRightScore = 0


/*    @IBAction func checkScore(sender: UIButton) {
    if topLeftScore + topCenterScore + topRightScore == 3{
        topLeft.image = UIImage(named: "")
    }




}
*/

@IBAction func resetButtonAct(sender: UIButton) {
playerTurn = 0
topLeftB.enabled = true
topCenterB.enabled = true
topRightB.enabled = true
middleLeftB.enabled = true
middleCenterB.enabled = true
middleRightB.enabled = true
bottomLeftB.enabled = true
bottomCenterB.enabled = true
bottomRightB.enabled = true
    topLeft.image = UIImage(named: "")
    topCenter.image = UIImage(named: "")
    topRight.image = UIImage(named: "")
    middleRight.image = UIImage(named: "")
    middleLeft.image = UIImage(named: "")
    middleCenter.image = UIImage(named: "")
    bottomLeft.image = UIImage(named: "")
    bottomCenter.image = UIImage(named: "")
    bottomRight.image = UIImage(named: "")

    topLeftB.hidden = false
    topCenterB.hidden = false
    topRightB.hidden = false
    middleLeftB.hidden = false
    middleCenterB.hidden = false
    middleRightB.hidden = false
    bottomLeftB.hidden = false
    bottomCenterB.hidden = false
    bottomRightB.hidden = false
}


@IBAction func topLeft(sender: UIButton) {

    if playerTurn == 0 {

    topLeft.image = UIImage(named: "Xpix.png")
    playerTurn = playerTurn + 1
    topLeftB.enabled = false
    topLeftB.hidden = true
         topLeftScore = 1

    }
    else if playerTurn == 1 {
        topLeft.image = UIImage(named: "Opix.png")
         playerTurn = playerTurn - 1
        topLeftB.enabled = false
        topLeftB.hidden = true
        topLeftScore = 10
    }
 }

 @IBAction func topCenter(sender: UIButton) {
    topCenterB.hidden = true //included in both
    if playerTurn == 0 {

        topCenter.image = UIImage(named: "Xpix.png")
        playerTurn = playerTurn + 1
        topCenterB.enabled = false

         topCenterScore = 1

    }
    else if playerTurn == 1{
        topCenter.image = UIImage(named: "Opix.png")
        playerTurn = playerTurn - 1
        topCenterB.enabled = false
          topCenterScore = 10
    }

 }

 @IBAction func topRight(sender: UIButton) {
    topRightB.hidden = true //included in both
    if playerTurn == 0 {

        topRight.image = UIImage(named: "Xpix.png")
        playerTurn = playerTurn + 1
        topRightB.enabled = false
        topRightScore = 1


    }
    else if playerTurn == 1 {
        topRight.image = UIImage(named: "Opix.png")
        playerTurn = playerTurn - 1
        topRightB.enabled = false
        topRightScore = 10
    }



}

@IBAction func middleLeft(sender: UIButton) {
 middleLeftB.hidden = true   //included in both
    if playerTurn == 0 {

        middleLeft.image = UIImage(named: "Xpix.png")
        playerTurn = playerTurn + 1
        middleLeftB.enabled = false
        middleLeftScore = 1

    }
    else if playerTurn == 1 {
        middleLeft.image = UIImage(named: "Opix.png")
        playerTurn = playerTurn - 1
        middleLeftB.enabled = false
        middleLeftScore = 10
    }
}

@IBAction func middleCenter(sender: UIButton) {
   middleCenterB.hidden = true //included in both
    if playerTurn == 0 {

        middleCenter.image = UIImage(named: "Xpix.png")
        playerTurn = playerTurn + 1
        middleCenterB.enabled = false
        middleCenterScore = 1
    }
    else if playerTurn == 1 {
        middleCenter.image = UIImage(named: "Opix.png")
        playerTurn = playerTurn - 1
        middleCenterScore = 10
    }

 }


@IBAction func middleRight(sender: UIButton) {
middleRightB.hidden = true //included in both
if playerTurn == 0 {

        middleRight.image = UIImage(named: "Xpix.png")
        playerTurn = playerTurn + 1
        middleRightB.enabled = false
         middleRightB.hidden = true
        middleRightScore = 1
    }
    else if playerTurn == 1 {
        middleRight.image = UIImage(named: "Opix.png")
        playerTurn = playerTurn - 1
        middleRightB.enabled = false
         middleRightB.hidden = true
        middleRightScore = 10
    }


}


@IBAction func bottomLeft(sender: UIButton) {
   bottomLeftB.hidden = true
    if playerTurn == 0 {

        bottomLeft.image = UIImage(named: "Xpix.png")
        playerTurn = playerTurn + 1
        bottomLeftB.enabled = false
        bottomRightScore = 1

    }
    else if playerTurn == 1 {
        bottomLeft.image = UIImage(named: "Opix.png")
        playerTurn = playerTurn - 1
    bottomLeftB.enabled = false
        bottomRightScore = 10
    }

}


@IBAction func bottomCenter(sender: UIButton) {
bottomCenterB.hidden = true
    if playerTurn == 0 {

        bottomCenter.image = UIImage(named: "Xpix.png")
        playerTurn = playerTurn + 1
        bottomCenterB.enabled = false
        bottomCenterScore = 1

    }
    else if playerTurn == 1 {
        bottomCenter.image = UIImage(named: "Opix.png")
        playerTurn = playerTurn - 1
    bottomCenterB.enabled = false
        bottomCenterScore = 10
    }


}


@IBAction func bottomRight(sender: UIButton) {
    bottomRightB.hidden = true
    if playerTurn == 0 {

        bottomRight.image = UIImage(named: "Xpix.png")
        playerTurn = playerTurn + 1
        bottomRightB.enabled = false
        bottomRightScore = 1

    }
    else if playerTurn == 1 {
        bottomRight.image = UIImage(named: "Opix.png")
        playerTurn = playerTurn - 1
    bottomRightB.enabled = false
        bottomRightScore = 10
    }

    }//ends last function




}
```

Comment: "this is the code i have for my while statement, but it will not work."
It would help if you explained what doesn't work. Does it not compile? Does the i not get updated? Does the loop never end? "will not work" can cover so many possibilities that we wouldn't even know where to begin to think about what could be wrong much less what a possible solution might be.

Comment: Have you actually tried running the code? It works for me, and I think you're prematurely thinking your code is wrong because the Xcode syntax correction tool is doing exactly that (sometimes it gets ahead of itself). Hit run and it will work.

Comment: @jonogilmour yes, ive run the code and it gives me the red !, with it saying Expected Declaration.

Comment: Except you haven't shown anything. You need to actually give us the whole code (including parts before this), because what you have given us absolutely works, I tested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written that code (the while loop) at a class level. You need to move it to a function for your code to compile.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
// your code was here

    function functionLevel() -> Void {
         var i = 0
         while (i < 5) {
              i++
         }

    }
}
```

Comment: +1, was just about to post this. The actual *usefulness* of this code isn't clear, I assume OP was just having a play around with Swift..?

Comment: @jonogilmour I assume so.

Comment: @jonogilmour Im attempting to make a tic-tac-toe game for my IOS Dev class, and this is how im going to check the winning values this way. Would there be a better way to go about it? As you can see in func topLeft, it sets the topRightScore to 1 if its player X, and 10 if its player O, so if a row adds to 3 Player X wins, and if it adds to 30, player O wins. Could i do it differently?

Comment: Ask this in a different question.